# How can I sort with the timestamp in the filename

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a list of files in the directory having different time stamps as part of the file names. I want to sort the files based on the timestamp on the filename. (I do not want to sort based on the time/-t property of the file. Rather I want to sort based on the timestamp on the file-name)

Example files in the directory:

```
ABC.20200131224353
ABC.20080131214253
ABC.20200131234153
```

I have used regular `ls` as it sorts by file name, by default. But it is not working correctly for all cases. For example, if the year on the file is '2008', then it is not giving that file as earliest file.

Comment: Welcome, a doubt raised by @Olivier Dulac, are these the full names of the files, or just part of them?

Comment: There is no year `2008` in the example. There error is probably it something that you have chosen not to show us.

Comment: I get exactly the expected result with plain `ls` for your example files, what do you get? And ist that plain `ls` or maybe an alias that includes some options?

Comment: I think your sample filenames are slightly misleading -- given the same initial parts of the filename, `ls` would sort them how you want. Perhaps the actual filenames don't all start with the same letters? What are some safely anonymized filenames? Feel free to change letters, but leave anything that has a consistent structure (length of the date suffix, dots or dashes, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Extending a little the example:

```
ABC.20020131224353
ABC.20080131214253
ABC.20200131234153
ABC.20220131224353
ABC.20040131214253
ABC.20200131234153
```

You can use `find` and `sort`:

```bsh
$ find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*\.[0-9]{14}$' | sort -t. -k3,3
./ABC.20020131224353
./ABC.20040131214253
./ABC.20080131214253
./ABC.20200131224353
./ABC.20200131234153
./ABC.20220131224353
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `-X` switch with GNU `ls`. For example, in one of my Documents directories, `/bin/ls -lX` returns this:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 me me 26595 Oct 28 10:39 "Mom's Books.ods"
-rw-r--r--  1 me me 80977 Jan 29 16:47 'My Investments.ods'
-rw-r--r--  1 me me 21338 Dec 20 12:31 'Good-Bad Foods.odt'
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me 51614 Jan 27 19:12 'Neuropathy Exercises.odt'
-r--------  1 me me   151 Jan 11 21:35  brave-browser-sync.txt
-r--------  1 me me   474 May 19  2020  brave_wallet_recovery.txt
-r--------  1 me me   882 Jan 30 13:39  seckeys.txt
-r--------  1 me me   120 Aug 20 11:48  toms-hardware-recovery.txt
```

Comment: the OP specifically need to sort according to the timestamp in the file name and not the file date itself...

Comment: @OlivierDulac - the `-X` switch sorts by the extension, not the timestamp, which is exactly what the OP asked for.

Comment: your exemple weren't clear on what -X did.. and apparently it is not posix: on my aix for exemple: man ls show this for -X : "Prints long user names when used with other flags that display user names. The upper limit is determined by the max_logname ODM attribute..." . besides I suspect the exemples given show just the portion he needs to sort, not the full filename with the final extension...

Comment: As a former IBMer, I should know better! I will fix my answer; thank you for this.